# Can I use the same keystore for multiple kafka producer/consumer

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I want to use SSL encryption and authentication, but we have many clients and we don't want to generate new keystore for each client, is it possible to use the same keystore for each clients and if yes what are the possible problem with this configuration.

Comment: Do you mean create a keystore on one computer and then copy to other computers? I don't remember if a keystore is tied to a physical machine.

Comment: are you talking about two-way SSL (= with client certificate) ?

Comment: @johnhanley No i mean have one key per "user group" and they can use it on many producer/consumer

Comment: EugèneAdell yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confluent say that you can't use the same keystore for each client. But you can use the same truststore for all.

https://docs.confluent.io/2.0.0/kafka/ssl.html#configuring-kafka-clients

Answer (score 0):

Keystore is used to store private key and identity certificates that a specific program should present to both parties (server or client) for verification. Private key need not be shared only public key.

Truststore is used to store certificates from Certified Authorities (CA) that verify the certificate presented by the server in SSL connection